# Libre office version

Tags: libreoffice

I'm running Libre office Version: 6.0.7.3 Build ID: 1:6.0.7-on an Asus laptop with Ubuntu 18.04. I use Synaptic for my updates and yet I'm nowhere near the version 6.3... others seem to be running, and now 6.4 is on offer to Windows users.

What should I do to "get up to date"

Any help and advice will be much appreciated.
Hal.

Comment: https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Libreoffice is available as a `deb`-package and as a `snap`- package.

While the `deb`-package provides version `6.0.7.3`, the `snap`-package comes with version `6.4.1.2`

You can install the libreoffice-`snap` with

```
snap install libreoffice
```

You can have both versions installed in your sysytem. If you want to remove the `deb`-package, you can do that with

```
sudo apt remove libreoffice*
```

Comment: Thank you to both mkko765 and Kurankat for your time in responding, I chose mook765's solution because  I have other snap packages installed.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @mook765's excellent suggestion of installing the Libreoffice `snap`, it is also available as a `flatpak`, which has the advantage of a much quicker startup time.

Snaps are getting much better, but the startup time when you open the application can still be noticeably long.

In order to use flatpaks you have to install [`flatpak`](https://flatpak.org/), which is available in the Ubuntu repositories:

`sudo apt install flatpak`

You can add the plugin to integrate with Ubuntu Software Center, if you use it:

`sudo apt install gnome-software-plugin-flatpak`

And finally install flathub:

`flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo`

Once that's done, you can install flatpaks, for LibreOffice it would be:

`sudo flatpak install org.libreoffice.LibreOffice`